# How to program when type arguments of generic type are known at runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a data store code base which use generic types for apis so that users can program nicely against `Key` and `Value`.

E.g.

```
db.AddAsync<Key,Value>(Key k, Value v)
DBEnumerator<Key,Value> db.GetAsyncEnumerator<Key,Value>()
```

Now, for some feature, we have these `Key` and `Value` types loaded from another dll at runtime. So, I have

```
string keyFullTypeName = this.keyTypeName, valueFullTypeName = this.valueTypeName;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.dllPath))
{
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(this.dllPath);

   Console.WriteLine("Loaded assembly : FullName: {0}", assembly.FullName);

   keyFullTypeName += ", " + assembly.FullName;
   valueFullTypeName += ", " + assembly.FullName;
}

Type keyType = Type.GetType(keyFullTypeName);
Type valueType = Type.GetType(valueFullTypeName);
var enumerator = db.GetType()
  .GetMethod("GetAsyncEnumerator")
  .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { keyType, valueType });
```

Now, how can I cast, enumerator to `DBEnumerator<Key,Value>` where `Key` is value of `keyType` and `Value` is value of `valueType`?

I have more 50 lines and I don't want to use reflection all the way. 
What are the best practices and helper methods in this situation?

Comment: You would call a method using your `MakeGenericMethod` that then does the hard work.

Comment: It would be awesome if you'd turn your "E.g." code into valid C# code.

Comment: Unfortunately, as a *consumer* of generic types or methods, you're expected to know the types at *your* compile time, unless a) you just use tonnes of reflection, which you've said you don't want or b) are also *providing* generic functionality yourself.

Comment: @Enigmativity awesome.. Your first comment is what solved it for me. I wonder, how i could not find it on my own.. I will mark yours as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this to get yourself into a strongly-typed situation at run-time.

```
void Main()
{
    var keyType = typeof(string);
    var valueType = typeof(int);
    var method = this.GetType()
        .GetMethod("RunMyGenericCode", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .MakeGenericMethod(keyType, valueType);
    method.Invoke(this, new [] { new DB() });
}

private void RunMyGenericCode<Key, Value>(DB db)
{
    DBEnumerator<Key, Value> e = db.GetAsyncEnumerator<Key, Value>();
    /* Now I'm strongly-typed */
}
```